# How to get last not-null value from row on Google Sheet

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, row, reversing

[dataset snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzYFc.png)

I would like to analyze this dataset with growth rate among years but first I need to take less recent and more recent stats achieved. Every row refers to a different country and much of them got less recent rate than 2020 one, so I need to get the last not-null value from every row in order to calculate growth rate among first stats and last one for each country. I manage to get less not-null cell putting it into 'Recent' column but I cant find a way to get the more recent one.Which formula should I use in AF2?
Consider that rates goes from E2 to AD2

I tried to reverse row order in order to use the same formula as I did in Recent but it wasn't successful

Comment: Consider providing input and expected output as **plain text table** in the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easy to copy/paste**.  Avoid sharing [links like spreadsheets](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455), which make the question useless for others or [images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551), which are hard to copy. Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
=CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(E2:AD2,E2:AD2<>""),-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Or, slightly more compactly:

```
=CHOOSECOLS(TOROW(E2:AD2,1),-1)
```